# .htaccess redirect with a variable?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need your help.

I want to redirect a URL like:

http://test.mydomain.com/tag/4

to

http://test.mydomain.com/tag/tag.php?id=4

The number is a variable and can change of course. Hope you have a solution for me.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /tag

    and now?..
```

I'm a total newbie in .htaccess!

Thanks for your short help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add this line to your .htaccess file

```
Redirect 301 http://test.mydomain.com/tag/4 http://test.mydomain.com/tag/tag.php?id=4
```

This is best done using the pages path. Here's an example:

```
Redirect 301 /tag/4.html http://test.mydomain.com/tag/tag.php?id=4
```

This should give you all you need http://www.htaccessredirect.co.uk/

Given that you're talking about redirection from said page using what the user types:
Create a text box and a button like this `<button onclick="redit();">`

Then add this function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redir(){
       var page = document.getElementById("textArea").value;
       location.href = "http://test.mydomain.com/tag/tag.php?id=" + page;
    };
</script>
```

This will send the user to the page you want them to, based on what they selected as page number.

Comment: Great - Thanks, the redirect works, but how can i make it variable (in general) 'cause i can't use a redirect-sheet with around 5000 lines. so i need to build it in general with variables in relation what the user types in..!

Comment: @cfurer Check the link I've added to my answer. You will find all you need there.

Comment: @cfurer Added something that might be useful for you. Don't forget to mark my answer as correct if this helped you. Thanks

Comment: Redirect 301 /tag/3 http://test.mydomain.com/tag/tag.php?id=3
This works fine.
But is there no possibility to set /tag/(.*) and at the end with $1 and so on?

Comment: I'm afraid that will not work well.
The most simple and quick thing you can do is to automaticly generate the lines you need from `Redirect 301 /tag/1 test.mydomain.com/tag/tag.php?id=1` to `Redirect 301 /tag/lastpage test.mydomain.com/tag/tag.php?id=lastpage` and just paste them there.